# Why to use print() every time inside function in r

Tags: r

I have a function that have nested functions. I call the sub functions inside the main function body, but the problem is that the methods such as `head()` or `ggplot` don't print to the command line. Is there any option in R to let those function print without nesting those functions inside `print()` method

```
x <- function(sample_dataframe){
   y <- function(df){
       head(df)
       # do more stuff on the dataframe ..
       return df
   } 
   y(sample_dataframe)
}
x()
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [create a reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: For what it’s worth, `print` is pretty much *only* for interactive usage: the function *never* needs to be called manually. Instead, more appropriate functions for producing messages/text are `message`, `warning`, `cat`, etc. And for plotting, well, `plot`. `plot` also works for ‘ggplot2’ objects.

Comment: One other comment:  `return df` is not legal R code.  Unlike some other languages (C, for example),  `return()` is a function in R.  You'll get a syntax error from `return df`, but a plain `return` is legal:  it just doesn't do what you think it should.

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't.  The functions `head()` and `ggplot()` *never* print anything.  They just return an object, and R decides whether to print that object or not.

The rule in R is that objects returned at the top level will print (unless they are marked as "invisible").  There's no option to make things automatically print in other circumstances.

The philosophy behind this difference is that R is intended to be used both interactively and programmatically.  In a program, if you want something to print, you should call a function to print it.  Weird automatic actions just cause trouble.  However, this is inconvenient if you are using R more like a calculator than a programming platform.  If you want to know the value of 123 times 456,  it's a lot easier to type `123*456` than to type `print(123*456)`, so the original interactive console would automatically print things unless you asked it not to do so.

In the years since that decision, things like R Markdown documents that blur the line between programming platform and interactive calculator have come along.

You find the programmatic requirement to specify your actions inconvenient:  you'd like `123*456` in a program to print its result.  The trouble with that behaviour is that there are functions in R that are called for their side effects (deleting files, opening graphics devices, etc.) and some of them return information that will print when they are called interactively, but will be ignored if they are called in a program.  It is already inconvenient to have to use `invisible()` to suppress printing of function results; it would be even more inconvenient to have to use `invisible()` on every function call where you didn't save the result in a variable.

Comment: But see my comment. `print` is the wrong function 100% of the time in written code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Your comment is wrong.  If you want the formatting that `print()` provides, then use `print()`.

Comment: No, the comment is correct: `format` should provide the same formatting, if the type you want to format is properly implemented. I’m aware this isn’t always the case, in which case using `print` may serve as a workaround. But it’s strictly a hack. `print` is *designed* for interactive use, and is simply the S3 generic that gets called automatically when an object is printed on the interactive console output. It isn’t *intended* for being invoked in code, which explains why its output can’t be stored directly, for example (you’d need to `capture.output` it).

Comment: Isn't little weird in the development of a language to let something works sometime and sometimes not? at least there should be a passable argument to enable/disable :(

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph , I agree with you, but moving from print to format, isn't the desired solution as it much code in both cases.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  Please show us the code that's equivalent to `print(1:100)` and `print(head(mtcars))`.  Or are integer vectors and dataframes not properly implemented?

Comment: @Ahmed:  I'll edit my answer to explain some motivation for this.

Comment: @user2554330 I don’t know what you mean. `format(1 : 100)` works as expected. So does `format(head(mtcars))`, except you can’t pass it directly to `cat` since all columns are formatted separately. But the result of `print(head(mtcars))` is also not directly usable *except for interactive programming/debugging*. It has no place inside a function. It’s really bad practice to have functions spew random stuff like that. Of course there’s no reason to be *dogmatic* about it but it’s a quite fundamental guideline: *don’t* use `print` in functions, use the appropriate `message` function.

Comment: @KonradRudolph:  This conversation isn't appropriate here, so let's leave it at that.